# Passing optional parameter in router using connect-route

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i make api with default GET request and with optional parameter routing behave differently ? I'm using using connect-route for routing.

```
var connectRoute = require('connect-route'),
  connect = require('connect'),
  app = connect();

app.use(connectRoute(function (router) {
  router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    defaultRequest();
  });

  router.get('/:param', function (req, res, next) {
    processParams();
  });}));
```

Right  now when i do the default request "https://localhost/" it will call both 'defaultRequest' & 'processParam' methods because the route will match both. But i want to handle these two calls separately like

- call for "https://localhost/" should call only "defaultRequest" and
- call for "https://localhost/params" should call only "processParams" 
  and

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the 2 routes and check for the existence of that param to conditionally perform an action:

```
var connectRoute = require('connect-route'),
  connect = require('connect'),
  app = connect();

app.use(connectRoute(function (router) {
  router.get('/:param', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.param) {
      processParams();
    } else {
      defaultRequest();
    }
  });
}));
```